# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { }} to activity

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have a method that gives users the option to use the camera intent to capture a photo to then upload to the application:

```
public void UploadImageToFeed() {

        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"Gallery", "Take a Picture"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Upload an Image");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_image);
        builder.setItems(colors, (dialog, which) -> {
            if (which == 0) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            } else {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "camera.jpg");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

When a camera image is taken, I process the image to reduce its size before it is actually uploaded. This is where I get a crash.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    ImageView imageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
                    imageToUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    int nh = (int) (yourSelectedImage.getHeight() * (512.0 / yourSelectedImage.getWidth()));
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, 512, nh, true);
                    imageToUpload.setImageBitmap(scaled);

                }
        }
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/197149/ORIGINAL/NONE/724456777 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F197149/ORIGINAL/NONE/724456777} }} to activity {com.yitter.android/com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0


at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:829)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:739)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:615)
                                                                        at com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity$override.onActivityResult(YeetActivity.java:350)
                                                                        at com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity$override.access$dispatch(YeetActivity.java)
                                                                        at com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity.onActivityResult(YeetActivity.java:0)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My first suspicion was that the error occurs where I'm scaling the camera image down, but it's not so obvious from my stack trace. When I remove the two lines of code responsible for rescaling the image, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.yitter.android/com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                      at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
                                                                      at com.yitter.android.activity.YeetActivity.onActivityResult(YeetActivity.java:366)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`. You know the `Uri` where the image is supposed to be — you put it in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. You need to hold onto that location (including via the saved instance state `Bundle`) and look there.

Also note that `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+, once you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 25 or higher.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.3/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, including using `FileProvider` to avoid `Uri.fromFile()`.